# Card component with custom border inwards extension

Tags: css, reactjs, frontend

So I have a card with a border using div(see image). But how do I make that border extension at the bottom? I tried with a div and absolute positioning along with border-radius. Is that approach correct?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

have you inspected the element in the dev tools? I've seen some really creative uses of the ::before and ::after pseudo elements. I would start there.

https://youtu.be/YaONowiQKW8?list=TLPQMjEwNzIwMjJmQxJXUBa_tA

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).